# iOS 8.3 Safari new top 'no click zone' workarounds

Tags: ios, css

we have a mobile version of our website, with a fixed top navigation bar. The websize is basically a non scrollable single page webapp.

we already had to move footer links up in the navigation bar as interacting with the bottom 44 px would kick the user out of fullscreen mode, and that was fine for a while

since 8.3 users are getting kicked out fullscreen also when they click around the toopbar area: when a user clicks around the top area, the navigation bar pops up and pushes the content around

is there any known workaround to this? the screen size is already small and putting the navigation in the middle of the page is annoying for the user, that's where our main content is.